# Linux mint. Ошибка 452: out of range

Tags: linux, linux-mint, grub

Всем добрый день.
Когда перезагрузил ОС linux mint пишет **Grub Rescue**. Я его исправил написав эти команды

```
set prerix=(hd0,gpt3)/boot/grub
set root=(hd0,gpt3  
insmod normal
normal
```

Потом когда вошёл в ос пишет:
**452 out of range pointer: 0x9cffe020
Backtrace (.text 0xa055 .data 0x15d6c):
Aborted. Press any key to exit**

Помогите пожалуйста.